# why doesn't ajax fn() follow the code sequence

Tags: ajax

I just wanted to understand the coding flow of `ajax` function. let me give one simple example,

```
function test()  {   alert("Hello");   alert("World");     }
```

if you run this function, the first dialog would be `Hello` and the second would be `World`, Right? But why in ajax the coding structure doesn't go through in same fashion.

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "pos/write", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

ajaxRequest.send("user=Ram");  /* this line can be written anywhere  */

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                  alert("done");  }         
// ajaxRequest.send("user=Ram");
```

as you can see, `.send('user=Ram')` written above & below the `.readyState`, but it runs successfully in both case. ***This is what i want to understand, why doesn't `ajax` fn() follow  the code sequence***

Comment: Your js looks like it's missing something at the end...

Comment: @Ben: yes, i just written some part of the js where i am not getting the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that `.send()` is *asynchronous*. Immediately after `.send()` is called, you're wiring up the `onreadystatechange` handler on the same object that will eventually receive the response from `pos/write`. Even though it appears after the request was initiated, there will always be time for it to run and wire that handler up before the response comes back, the XHR object changes its `readyState` to `4`, and your `onreadystatechange` event handler is executed.

Comment: oh i see ` there will always be time for it to run and wire that handler up before the response comes back`. t got your point. Thanks Dave.